# htaccess rewriting wrong

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the following urls:

`https://example.com/@example_user/` (with or without end slash) to `https://example.com/main.php?user=example_user`

And `https://example.com/@example_user/config/` (with or without end slash) to
`https://example.com/main.php?user=example_user&site=config`

I was trying with the follwing script:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/?$ main.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main.php?user=$1&site=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But this happens:

- `https://example.com/@example_user` <-Works fine
- `https://example.com/@example_user/` <-rewrites wrong `https://example.com/@/@example_user/`
- `https://example.com/@example_user/config` <-Works fine
- `https://example.com/@example_user/config/` <-Rewrites wrong as `https://example.com/@%251/%252`

I tried everything I can, but I lack of more knowledge.

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess by editing this question?

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd examples are the _same_?! Or is that a typo? What do you mean by "rewrites wrong"? By allowing an optional trailing slash on the rewrite you are potentially creating a duplicate content issue (bad for SEO). If you need to allow an optional trailing slash then you should be _redirecting_ to the canonical URL (I assume _without_ the trailing slash). Otherwise, the rules you've posted look OK, so your problem maybe a conflict in your `.htaccess` file (hence why we need to see your full `.htaccess` file) or something else entirely.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, there was a missing slash at the end of the second example. Rewrites wrong means in this case that I get the URL changed to the one I wrote there: ` https://example.com/@/@example_user/` and of course, it doesn't work.

Btw: That's the full htaccess file

Comment: And yes, I don't want the trailing slash, so I would prefer to rewrite it!

Comment: "I get the URL _changed_ to..." - That would imply an external redirect, which the rules you've posted are not. Please confirm this (what 3xx HTTP status do you see in the network tools)? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache (301s are cached persistently by the browser).

Comment: @MrWhite I cleared the cache and now I got a new error. When ending in a trailing slash it happens as explained above (changes the url to https://example.com/@/@example_user/) in the first case. But in the second case (https://example.com/@example_user/config/) it returns the folowing URL https://example.com/@%251/%252

Comment: There is no apparent reason why this should be happening, simply based on the rules we have been shown so far. Maybe there is something else in your setup, on the vhost or the httpd configuration level, that influences the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that the problem was how the script handled the trailing slashes. So I solved the issue in the following way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/?$ /main.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /main.php?user=$1&site=$2 [L,QSA]
```